# js function is unidentified in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, partial-views

I have view in which renders some partial view. In this partial view i have js function.
This function i run in main view in document ready. 
Problem - in main view this function is null or unidentified. Why? 
I have also another views, where i also render that partial view, and everything works fine.

```
function InitProfileNavigation() {

    $('button.edit-profile').click(function() {
        window.location.hash = '<%: EnumUserProfilePage.ProfileEdit %>';
        return false;
    });

    $('.profile-nav-profile-overview a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        window.location.hash = '<%: EnumUserProfilePage.ProfileOverview %>';
        return false;
    });

    $('.profile-nav-profile-listings a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        window.location.hash = '<%: EnumUserProfilePage.Listings %>';
        return false;
    });
 }
```

Using function in View :

```
$(function() {
        InitProfileNavigation();
    });
```

---

This is only occurs in IE8. I add alerts after partial view renders and after function runs - In FireFox first alert - after partial, second - after func. But in IE8 - only displays alert after function.

---

Problem Resolved. It was incorect html layout in main view, which was rendere from db.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the function from the partial view and move to some `.js` file, and then include this `.js` file in your partial view?

Comment: Maybe, in this case you call InitProfileNavigation() function before it is even declared?

Comment: if i do it, how can i use i script '<%: EnumUserProfilePage.ProfileEdit %>' asp?

Comment: @Klemzy i render partial view before this script, but i check it again

Comment: you can use for example some `hiddenfield` and in your `.js` file just get the value from specific `hiddenfields`

Comment: I forget to add : This is only occurs in IE8.

Comment: You shouldn't forget such info ;)